# Compare Const char* and char *

Tags: c, network-programming, libpcap

I'm trying to compare the values in these two char pointers but i'm getting strange outputs:

The first one is (libpcap IP address):

```
const char* ip_source = inet_ntop(AF_INET, &ip->ip_src, buffer1, sizeof(buffer1)); //192.168.56.1
```

The second one is:

```
char *host_ip = inet_ntoa(((struct sockaddr_in*)a->addr)->sin_addr); //192.168.56.1
```

I've tried using `if (*ip_source == *host_ip)`, `if (strcmp(ip_source, host_ip) == 0)` and `if (strncmp(ip_source, host_ip, strlen(host_ip))`.

How do I compare the IP addresses stored in these two variables to see if both IP addresses are the same?

This is the code:

```
if (strncmp(ip_source, host_ip, strlen(host_ip)) == 0) // if sent local > remote
{
    printf("   RST/ACK Detected [Local > Remote]\n");
}
else // if sent remote > local
{
    printf("   RST/ACK Detected [Remote > Local]\n");
}
```

This is the result:

```
Packet number 2386:
current time: 2015-04-11 15:07:59.412 
  From(src): 192.168.56.1 <---- Local (IP stored in *host_ip)
    To(dst): 192.168.56.2 <---- Remote
   Protocol: TCP
   Src port: 1864
   Dst port: 49750
    Seq Num: 0
    Ack Num: 3556812524
   RST/ACK Detected [Remote > Local] <--- Wrong
```

In this case it's returning `-2`

Comment: What are those strange outputs?

Comment: It looks like its failing the test but it depends on the network data coming in, i'm trying to find out if its a problem with this `if` test, the database or the data.

Comment: @ValentinLorentz added it to the question

Comment: Why are you using `strncmp()` if you're using `strlen()`?

Comment: I found the problem, the host_ip variable was being over written with every packet captured.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams - strncmp() takes in a number of characters you want to compare doesn't it? - I want to compare them all so use strlen() of the variable?

Comment: The point of using `strncmp()` instead of `strcmp()` is that you know how many characters there are and you want to prevent accidental overruns. Using `strlen()` as the length completely undermines that.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams - Ah right, so if i do strcmp() it'll compare the whole string in an if statement, not just like 1 character or something?

Comment: yes, that's the difference between strcmp and equality.

Comment: @Crizly Since you have found the answer, post that answer and accept it to close this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Ths first would just compare the first character of each, while strcmp *looks* right to me. Should not matter if one is const and the other not.

Comment: I've tried using strncmp(ip_source, host_ip, strlen(host_ip) to compare all characters but it's still not working

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out the issue was with inet_ntoa rather than the string test.

The variable `host_ip` was being overwritten with every packet captured.

When I got the IP address I used this:

```
inet_ntoa(((struct sockaddr_in*)a->addr)->sin_addr);
```

But that dynamically overwrites every time a packet is captured, so changing it to the static:

```
const char* host_ip = inet_ntop(AF_INET, &(((struct sockaddr_in*)a->addr)->sin_addr), buffer1, sizeof(buffer1));
```

Method worked.

Comment: That's an issue with `inet_ntoa()`, not libpcap.  The man page on OS X says "The string returned by inet_ntoa() resides in a static memory area.", which is true on other OSes as well, and that means that if *any* other code calls `inet_ntoa()`, it overwrites the previous value.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just compare the addresses directly, as they're both in network byte order?

```
if (memcmp(&ip->ip_src, &((struct sockaddr_in*)a->addr)->sin_addr.s_addr, 4) == 0) {
    printf("   RST/ACK Detected [Local > Remote]\n");
} else {
    printf("   RST/ACK Detected [Remote > Local]\n");
}
```